# Docker build minimal image python 2.7 with scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, scrapy

I'm doing a docker image with Python 2.7 Alpine and scrapy to export my script towards my team.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN python -m pip install parse pyOpenSSL scrapy scrapy-xlsx
COPY scriptv1/ .
```

And when I `docker build -t python_space .`

it goes like this :

[image: log error docker]

At first I thought It was about cryptography not finding libssl-dev and that's why I'm doing "python -m pip install [...] pyOpenSSL [...] ".

I have no leads about what's going wrong :/.

Thanks for reading !

EDIT : I added RUN apk add build-base in order to build with gcc, different error pops out.

Second logs: [image: logerror2]

Comment: `pip install cryptography` compiles some sources and needs `gcc` for that. Add `RUN apk add build-base` before `RUN python ...`

Comment: Be aware that using `alpine` can actually make your container more bulky and result in longer builds, see [here](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/) for example

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm going to remove alpine and see what happens

Comment: @hurlenko I edited my original question, with a second screenshot describing what happens when docker build with run apk add build-base before RUN python ..

Comment: Ok ! Without `alpine` it just works, without RUN apk add build-base too.

My COPY is wrong too apparently ^^ `COPY failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder321498942/scriptv1: no such file or directory`

Comment: I can’t read these images at all, and I definitely wouldn’t be able to find your question later if I had the same problem.  Please replace these with the actual output of the `docker build` command, as text, inline in the question.  (...and consider using a version of Python that’s receiving security updates and other bug fixes!)

Answer (score 3):

This `Dockerfile` will build an image in two stages, keeping the build dependencies in a throw-away image:

```
FROM library/python:2.7-alpine AS build

RUN apk add gcc musl-dev libffi-dev libressl-dev

RUN mkdir /wheels
WORKDIR /wheels

RUN pip wheel cryptography==2.8


FROM library/python:2.7-alpine
RUN apk add libressl
COPY --from=build /wheels /wheels
RUN pip install /wheels/*.whl
```

The resulting image is 93 MB in size.

You might want to adapt it to your exact packages and build dependencies.

In your case adding your own lines to the **end** of the `Dockerfile` should be enough.

Comment: with pip wheel does that compile the package but not install it? What does that do?

Comment: It does the same as `pip install` with the exception that instead of installing it, the resulting build will be packaged into a wheel file. Which will then be copied and installed in the new image.

Answer (score 1):

A non-alpine Dockerfile using `python:2.7-slim`works fine, since it can use manylinux wheels.

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
RUN python -m pip install parse pyOpenSSL scrapy scrapy-xlsx
```

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:2.7-slim
 ---> 426ba9523d99
Step 2/2 : RUN python -m pip install parse pyOpenSSL scrapy scrapy-xlsx
 ---> Running in 853a571c7a66
# ... snip ...
Successfully installed Automat-20.2.0 PyDispatcher-2.0.5 PyHamcrest-1.10.1 Twisted-19.10.0 attrs-19.3.0 cffi-1.14.0 constantly-15.1.0 cryptography-2.8 cssselect-1.1.0 enum34-1.1.9 et-xmlfile-1.0.1 functools32-3.2.3.post2 hyperlink-19.0.0 idna-2.9 incremental-17.5.0 ipaddress-1.0.23 jdcal-1.4.1 lxml-4.5.0 openpyxl-2.6.4 parse-1.15.0 parsel-1.5.2 protego-0.1.16 pyOpenSSL-19.1.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pycparser-2.19 queuelib-1.5.0 scrapy-1.8.0 scrapy-xlsx-0.1.1 service-identity-18.1.0 six-1.14.0 w3lib-1.21.0 zope.interface-4.7.1
```

The resulting image is 232MB.